# d3 Insecure script

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am a newbie in JavaScript, and I have a ton of silly questions to ask.

Currently, I am exploring [d3](http://d3js.org) libraries. When I refer to the library (d3 and dimple) on the Web (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js), the browser (Chrome) throws an error (see the attached screenshot).

Even though I have resolved the issue by uploading the d3 and dimple files on the server, but I am curios how I could use a direct reference to the libraries?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwFCy.png)

Many thanks,

Eka

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many questions on the site.  Essentially you can't `<script src="http://`, if your page is loaded via `https`.  The "right" way to do this is to just use `<script src="//path/to/file.js" />`, the browser will then pick the proper protocol based on the initial page load.

Comment: Sorry, when I typed the question, I did not notice any related question. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you refer to the d3.js file with https:// in the front.

Comment: I do ) Check out the screenshot attached to the original post!